# Go deadlock all goroutines asleep

Tags: go, deadlock, goroutine

This is a follow up to my earlier post:

```
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34736825/goroutine-exit-status-2-what-does-it-mean-why-is-it-happening?noredirect=1#comment57238789_34736825
```

I'm still having trouble figuring out where the channels should be closed, after reading multiple topics and articles both on and off SO.

This program will open a list of files, create an output file for each input file (with the same name),visit all the urls in each input file and get all href links from these - which are saved to the corresponding output file. 
However, I'm getting the following error:

```
    http://play.golang.org/p/8X-1rM3aXC
```

The linkgetter, and getHref functions are mainly for processing. Head and tail are run as separate goroutines, and worker does the processing.

```
    package main

    import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/net/html"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "regexp"
    "sync"
    )

    type Work struct {
    Link     string
    Filename string
    }

    type Output struct {
    Href     string
    Filename string
    }

    func getHref(t html.Token) (href string, ok bool) {
    // Iterate over all of the Token's attributes until we find an    "href"
    for _, a := range t.Attr {
            if a.Key == "href" {
                    href = a.Val
                    ok = true
            }
    }
    return
    }

    func linkGetter(out chan<- Output, r io.Reader, filename string) {
    z := html.NewTokenizer(r)
    for {
            tt := z.Next()
            switch {
            case tt == html.ErrorToken:
                    return
            case tt == html.StartTagToken:
                    t := z.Token()
                    isAnchor := t.Data == "a"
                    if !isAnchor {
                            continue
                    }

                    // Extract the href value, if there is one
                    url, ok := getHref(t)
                    if !ok {
                            continue
                    }

                    out <- Output{url, filename}
            }
    }
    }

    func worker(out chan<- Output, in <-chan Work, wg *sync.WaitGroup)    {
    defer wg.Done()
    for work := range in {
            resp, err := http.Get(work.Link)
            if err != nil {
                    continue
            }
            body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
            if err != nil {
                    continue
            }
            if err = resp.Body.Close(); err != nil {
                    fmt.Println(err)
            }
            linkGetter(out, bytes.NewReader(body), work.Filename)
    }
    }

    func head(c chan<- Work) {
    r, _ := regexp.Compile("(.*)(?:.json)")
    files, _ := filepath.Glob("*.json")

    for _, elem := range files {
            res := r.FindStringSubmatch(elem)
            for k, v := range res {

                    if k == 0 {
                            outpath, _ :=  filepath.Abs(fmt.Sprintf("go_tester/%s", v))

                            abspath, _ := filepath.Abs(fmt.Sprintf("url_links/%s", v))
                            f, _ := os.Open(abspath)
                            scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)

                            for scanner.Scan() {
                                    c <- Work{outpath, scanner.Text()}
                            }

                    }
            }

    }


    }

    func tail(c <-chan Output) {
    currentfile := ""
    var f *os.File
    var err error
    for out := range c {
            if out.Filename != currentfile {
                    if err = f.Close(); err != nil { // might cause an error on first run
                            fmt.Println(err)
                    }
                    f, err = os.OpenFile(out.Filename, os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0600)
                    if err != nil {
                            log.Fatal(err)
                    }
                    currentfile = out.Filename
            }
            if _, err = f.WriteString(out.Href + "\n"); err != nil {
                    fmt.Println(err)
            }
    }

    }

    const (
    nworkers = 80
    )

    func main() {
    //fmt.Println("hi")
    in := make(chan Work)
    out := make(chan Output)

    go head(in)
    go tail(out)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < 85; i++ {
            wg.Add(1)
            go worker(out, in, &wg)
    }
    close(in)   
    close(out)    
    wg.Wait()


    }
```

What is wrong with the way the channels are closed?

Comment: I could be wrong ... but, you're closing them before the waitgroup `Wait()` call. This means that by the time the scheduler is running your goroutines they'll be closed and your `Done()` calls on the wait group can never run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not really paying attention to your pipeline design here. You have to ask yourself "When is section X done? What should happen when it is done? What happens after it is done?" for every section of the pipeline.

You start up `head`, `tail`, and `worker` to range over channels. The only way these functions are going to return successfully is if these channels are closed.

Draw it out of you need to.

1. `head(in)` feeds in to `in`
2. `worker(out, in, &wg)` ranges over `in`, feeds into `out`, and tells you it is done with `wg` once `in` is closed
3. `tail(out)` ranges over `out`

So what do you need to do to:

1. Make sure all input is processed?
2. Make sure all goroutines return?

Like so:

1. You need to close `in` from `head` once it is done processing all of the files.
2. This will cause `worker` to actually return once all items it can get from `in` are processed, causing `wg.Wait()` to return
3. it is now safe to close `out` since nothing is feeding in to it and this will cause `tail` to eventually return.

But you'll probably need another `sync.WaitGroup` associated with `tail` for this particular design because the whole program will exit right when `wg.Wait()` returns, thus possibly not finishing all of the work that `tail` is doing. [See here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_execution). Specifically:

> Program execution begins by initializing the main package and then
>   invoking the function main. When that function invocation returns, the
>   program exits. It does not wait for other (non-main) goroutines to
>   complete.

You'll probably also want to use buffered channels [referenced here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Channel_types) to aid in not having switch execution between goroutines so much. With your current design you're wasting a lot of time with context switching.